# How to display complex object attributes in form fields in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a JSON object with the structure below which I want to display in a form for edit when I clicked on edit button on my table row.

**json**

```
{
 "id": 123, 
 "name": "Paul", 
 "cars": [
    {
     "type": "toyota", 
     "year": "2013"
    },
    {
     "type": "audi", 
     "year": "2010"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need help on how to display the `type` of each `cars` object in my table file separated by comma(`,`). I got the object `id` and `name` displayed but not attributes in the cars array. How do I complete my `.ts` code so that the `type` of each car could show up in my table.

**.ts**

```
showRowDetail( data: any ) {
   this.formData.controls.id.setValue( data.id );
   this.formData.controls.name.setValue( data.name );
   //how do I update here to set the cars: types
}
```

**.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>ID:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control"
         formControlName="id">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" class="form-control"
        formControlName="name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Cars:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" 
        formControlName="cars">
</div>
```

I omitted the `*ngFor` table code, the  `showRowDetail` function is used on the edit button, which when clicked it opens a modal that present the form where the object data are shown. `data.id` and `data.name` fields are working, just the cars `type` I needed help with.

Comment: Show the HTML for type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to display the "type" of each "cars" object in my table file
>   seperated by comma(,)

Generate comma separated `type` values from `cars`array using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```
showRowDetail( data: any ) {
   this.formData.controls.id.setValue( data.id );
   this.formData.controls.name.setValue( data.name );

   let types = data.cars.map(car => car.type).join(", ");
   this.formData.controls.cars.setValue(types);
}
```

Comment: When I click the edit button, I got this error: "Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
    at MyComponent.showRowDetail"

Comment: @Pleasure - Make sure you have `formControlName="cars"` in your template. If `id` and `name` are working, then this should also work. If you are still having trouble, reproduce this code in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com) or similar site, I'll take a look.

Comment: Do you know if I can parse the "types" to an "ng-select" so that they are in the form of buttons and not just separated by comma?

Comment: @Pleasure - Yes, you can create various types of input elements as you wish. I haven't worked with `ng-select` yet.

Comment: the .map is no more working. When I click the button that uses the function, I got this error in console: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined", but when I comment out the line with the .map, the function works as normal. Has the .map stop working? Thanks